# How to create a Clone of database when we have two different Snowflake accounts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to clone the PROD database into non prod account for some reports testing. PROD and Non-prod are two different snowflake accounts so there is i am not able to do a direct clone of the database.
Are they any other options i can consider?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to clone between two different accounts. If Snowflake is able to do that, I would say that will be a great piece of engineering. The reason why I say this is because in case of a clone, the partitions are mapped to the new table in the metadata repository, there is not real copy of data. But as new data gets inserted, the new table will gradually shift away from the original and metadata will be updated accordingly. So, if this has to be done in multiple accounts you will need to have a global metadata repository.

Anyway, if I were given this problem I would have solved this as below

1. Create an external stage on AWS or Azure or GCP(whichever is being used). I have done this on AWS
2. Unload your prod data into the external stage
3. Then in the dev environment load your dev tables from the external stage

Data sharing would have been another option. But I think data sharing works within same region. If both your accounts are in the same region, you can try data sharing. I have not tried this option

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-gs.html

Comment: Thank You Rajib for your comment. I have hundreds of tables to load in DEV. I am not sure if i unload the data into files will work. I will try the data share option between accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone data to other accounts.  You want to Data Share your data to your other account.  This is what our strategy is for getting production data into lower environments for development, testing and DevOps activities.

Comment: I am looking into doing this - it seems the best way to do it. Is to share Production into Development environments. For your 'Transformation' code do you have it read from the shares to do the development and then switch it back to the true Development source? I have always wondered that. We do have use cases where people want to use our lower environments because they are hooked up to other system lower environments.

Answer (score 0):

Good article about the different setup here

[SNOWFLAKE DTAP ENVIRONMENT SETUP](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-DTAP-Environment-Setup)